# Python Print statement comes out blank output

Tags: python, function, printing

I apologize if this seems very basic, I'm new to Python and learning.  I have a task I'm working on but I can't seem to get the print to work in my function.  When I run it, I get nothing, no output.  I've tried looking up the basics for this, but maybe it's so simple I'm overlooking it? Any guidance would be appreciated.

*# create a function which receives two integers as input, adds them. Run your function with integers 2 and 8, and save the output to a new variable called myNewSum. Print myNewSum.  expected outcome: 10*

```
num1 = int(2)
num2 = int(8)

def add_numb(num1, num2):
    myNewSum = num1 + num2
    print(myNewSum)
```

Comment: are you calling `add_numb`?

Comment: BTW, you don't need `num1 = int(2)`. `2` is an integer, so `num1 = 2` is enough.

Comment: Another side note, depending on the intention, and pickiness, of this problem you may want to read the statement more closely, do they want you to print the value returned by the function or print the value in the function?

Answer (score 2):

Call your function:

```
add_numb(2, 8)
```

EDIT ( Since you're learning ):

```
num = int(2) # int() is redundant here as Python already knows that 2 is an int
```

Comment: Your method call doesn't match your definition, `add_numb` vs `add_num`

Answer (score 0):

You did all right, just forget to call function.
You just defined function, start to use it.
You can read more about in [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

```
add_numb(num1, num2)
```

Output:

```
10
```

---

Also, as @Matthias told in comments, you don't need to use `int()`:

```
num1 = 2
num2 = 8
# lets check type of variable:
type(num1)

int
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include a main function to your python program it makes it more reusable and I think easier to understand whats going on. For more information on the main follow this [link](https://www.guru99.com/learn-python-main-function-with-examples-understand-main.html).

I changed the global variable num1 and num2 from your example to var1 and var2, to emphasize the difference between global variables and parameters of a function.

```
var1 = 2
var2 = 8

def add_numb(num1, num2):
    myNewSum = num1 + num2
    print(myNewSum)

if __name__== "__main__":
    add_numb(var1, var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to call the method.

```
num1 = int(2)
num2 = int(8)

def add_numb(num1, num2):
        myNewSum = num1 + num2
        print(myNewSum)

add_numb(num1, num2)  #calling the method
```